# api response not coming in swagger documentation after hitting the execute

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I made an API document for one of my post requests.  I added the request body and there is no error in that, but when I hit execute under trying it, it just loads and closes after some time without giving any success message or error message which is coming from API. I check the network console that the success message is coming from API. How to show this success message in swagger ui.

Here is my API documentation

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /sign-up:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Create a JSONPlaceholder user.
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               firstName:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: The user's name.
 *                 example: Leanne Graham
 *               lastName:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: user last name
 *                 example: kumar
 *               email:
 *                 type: email
 *                 description: user email
 *                 example: x.k@gmail.com
 *               phoneNumber:
 *                 type: number
 *                 description: user phone number
 *                 example: 97809808080
 *               password:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: user password
 *                 example: 5fghfhfg7hgh
 *   response:
 *     201:
 *     200:
 *       message: user registered successfully
 *       status: true
 *     400:
 *       status: false
 *       message: some error occur
 *       
*/
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the "Console" tab in dev tools?

Comment: @Helen no there is not an error in the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today.

When I hit execute, the page will tell you it's loading. After that, the loading animation will be hidden and the response will not be shown.

I checked the network tab and I can see the request being made. It is successful even.

However, what I have missed is defining the `responses` property. Once I defined that and provided one entry, the response is showing.

In your snippet, you defined `response`, instead of `responses` which could be the problem.